# Xfce4 overrode my GNOME notifications (notify-osd). How do I get them back?

Tags: notification, notify-osd

I installed xfce4 (`sudo apt-get install xfce4`) and now in an ordinary Ubuntu (unity) session I'm getting light-colored (what I'm assuming are xfce's) notification bubbles. How do I revert this back to notify-osd?

Answer (score 1):

from http://www.techmansworld.com/2012/07/how-to-restore-unitys-notification.html

So first off, open up a terminal You can do this by accessing the applications menu from XFCE, or in Unity by opening the dash and typing in “terminal”. Once the terminal is open, paste the following line into the terminal and press enter.

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service
```

After pressing enter, you should receive a prompt for your password because this is modifying high level parts of your system. Just enter your password and continue. A new gedit (text editor) window should open with that config file.

All you have to do now is replace one line of text in that file. In that file, just replace following line:

```
Exec=/usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
```

with

```
Exec=/usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
```

**Note**
For **64 bit** installations replace:

```
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
```

with

```
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd/notify-osd
```

After that, save the file and log out. Log back in, and you should see Unity's notification system back. *Note that after doing this, you will also get GNOME's notification system in XFCE*.

If you do change your mind and want XFCE's notification system back, just edit that file again and paste the first line back to where the second line is located.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but, in my case (with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - 32bit) I replaced the  line

```
Exec=/usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
```

with this one:

```
Exec=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/notify-osd
```

because the executable notify-osd was there, instead being in /usr/lib/notify-osd/.

After that, I recovered the volume and brightness OSD notifications!

Answer (score 0):

Exact same thing happened to me, but accepted answer did not work on Ubuntu 16.04. To solve it, I just needed to remove the package `xfce4-notifyd`.

`sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd`

Please note this will force XFCE environment to use Ubuntu's `notify-osd` library.