# Restoring Ubuntu's default notification manager

Tags: 16.04, notify-osd, xmonad

Recently I installed i3 and Xmonad for testing purposes, and already got rid of them. However, when I log into Ubuntu's default window manager (Unity), the notifications are now broken.

For instance, when I adjust the volume, no notification is displayed. Also, other applications are now using a strange notification popup (see image below).

[image: Strange notification popup]

I think that the solution should be something on the lines of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150438/xfce4-overrode-my-gnome-notifications-notify-osd-how-do-i-get-them-back), but since I'm using the default window manager for Ubuntu 16.04 and not XFCE I don't know how this applies.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved: i3 automatically installs a notification manager called `dunst`. Simply removing it did the trick:

```
sudo apt purge dunst
```

Restart Ubuntu after the removal and everything should be fixed.